# how to grant a user to only access the performance area of the configuration screen drupal 7

Tags: users, caching, configuration

I would like to give my content editors the ability to flush the website Drupal cache. I can't seem to give them this privilege without also giving them the privilege to do everything in the configuration tab. Can I only give them permissions to clear the cache? (Obviously this in addition to editing content) I am using Drupal 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write a simple custom module to do this for you.
as you can see.with [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) you can alter all menu in drupal. And by overriding it's access callback you can have your custom function to grant access to your users. Here is a sample code that check if user has an 'editor' role.then it return true and user can access performance.

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/config/development/performance']['access callback'] = '_accesscheck';
}

function _accesscheck(){
  global $user;
  if(in_array('editor', $user->roles)){
     return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: This didn't give editor the option of clearing the cache. It does seem to give the permissions because if I take out the admin from the access check it removes the option to clear the cache. How do I let the editor get to the performance area since the editor now has permissions?

Comment: Actually I didn't quiet check this becous of time here "midnight" .but you can creat a block by hook_block_info or menu callback by hook_menu.and render a custom form on it that only contain a submit button.and on submitting that form you can call a function cache_clear_all(). If it isn't clear for you.i will write this code first thing tommorow

Comment: I actually got it to work by giving the user permissions to access the config and then taking away everything but the performance option. It was easy to take out everything I needeed. For exeample, in config there is a section called media I took out the whole section by just referencing admin/config/media']['access callback'] etc. Now I am working on taking everything else under the development tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Flush page cache](https://drupal.org/project/flush_page_cache) module, using this module you can set permission for granting clear-cache options to certain **Roles**.

> Features
>
> - Many button placement options including: in the page footer, with a
>     block, or if you use the Administration Menu module, a link is
>     included there as well.
> - The ability to define specific cache objects
>     to be cleared when flushing page caches.
> - Varnish integration, which
>     also purges the cached page from Varnish.

Comment: I noticed that in the notes it says that this module may only cache for me. It says to get around this, you can define custom cache IDs, tables, and paths on the configuration page. Does this mean I have to do this for each additional module?